TFLINT exiting on run
Whenever I try to run TFlint on my ubuntu machine I get an error. Just trying to get a basic tflint running from the repo install steps, im not sure whats going on
I've tried this locally and in CI
root@ee78a841acff:/app/infrastructure/terraform/us-east# tflint --version
TFLint version 0.53.0
+ ruleset.azurerm (0.26.0)
+ ruleset.terraform (0.9.1-bundled)

root@ee78a841acff:/app/infrastructure/terraform/us-east# cat .tflint.hcl
plugin "azurerm" {
  enabled = true
  version = "0.26.0"
  source  = "github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-azurerm"
}

plugin "terraform" {
  enabled = true
  preset  = "recommended"
}

root@ee78a841acff:/app/infrastructure/terraform/us-east# ls -l -a
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 29 04:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 20 02:52 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Aug 16 22:01 .terraform
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1183 Aug 29 03:23 .terraform.lock.hcl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  192 Aug 29 04:08 .tflint.hcl
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 16 21:34 env
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  697 Aug 20 03:23 main.tf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  155 Aug 29 03:09 versions.tf


root@ee78a841acff:/app/infrastructure/terraform/us-east# TFLINT_LOG=debug tflint --config=.tflint.hcl -v
TFLint version 0.53.0
04:41:56 config.go:147: [INFO] Load config: .tflint.hcl
04:41:56 config.go:347: [DEBUG] Config loaded
04:41:56 config.go:348: [DEBUG]   CallModuleType: local
04:41:56 config.go:349: [DEBUG]   CallModuleTypeSet: false
04:41:56 config.go:350: [DEBUG]   Force: false
04:41:56 config.go:351: [DEBUG]   ForceSet: false
04:41:56 config.go:352: [DEBUG]   DisabledByDefault: false
04:41:56 config.go:353: [DEBUG]   DisabledByDefaultSet: false
04:41:56 config.go:354: [DEBUG]   PluginDir:
04:41:56 config.go:355: [DEBUG]   PluginDirSet: false
04:41:56 config.go:356: [DEBUG]   Format:
04:41:56 config.go:357: [DEBUG]   FormatSet: false
04:41:56 config.go:358: [DEBUG]   Varfiles:
04:41:56 config.go:359: [DEBUG]   Variables:
04:41:56 config.go:360: [DEBUG]   Only:
04:41:56 config.go:361: [DEBUG]   IgnoreModules:
04:41:56 config.go:365: [DEBUG]   Rules:
04:41:56 config.go:369: [DEBUG]   Plugins:
04:41:56 config.go:371: [DEBUG]     azurerm: enabled=true, version=0.26.0, source=github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-azurerm
04:41:56 config.go:371: [DEBUG]     terraform: enabled=true, version=, source=
04:41:56 option.go:91: [DEBUG] CLI Options
04:41:56 option.go:92: [DEBUG]   CallModuleType: local
04:41:56 option.go:93: [DEBUG]   Force: false
04:41:56 option.go:94: [DEBUG]   Format:
04:41:56 option.go:95: [DEBUG]   Varfiles:
04:41:56 option.go:96: [DEBUG]   Variables:
04:41:56 option.go:97: [DEBUG]   EnableRules:
04:41:56 option.go:98: [DEBUG]   DisableRules:
04:41:56 option.go:99: [DEBUG]   Only:
04:41:56 option.go:100: [DEBUG]   EnablePlugins:
04:41:56 option.go:101: [DEBUG]   IgnoreModules:
04:41:56 discovery.go:90: [DEBUG] Find plugin path: /root/.tflint.d/plugins/github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-azurerm/0.26.0/tflint-ruleset-azurerm
04:41:56 discovery.go:54: [INFO] Plugin "azurerm" found
04:41:56 [DEBUG] cmdrunner/cmd_runner.go:73: starting plugin: path=/root/.tflint.d/plugins/github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-azurerm/0.26.0/tflint-ruleset-azurerm args=["/root/.tflint.d/plugins/github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-azurerm/0.26.0/tflint-ruleset-azurerm"]
04:41:56 [DEBUG] cmdrunner/cmd_runner.go:80: plugin started: path=/root/.tflint.d/plugins/github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-azurerm/0.26.0/tflint-ruleset-azurerm pid=1896
04:41:56 [DEBUG] go-plugin@v1.6.1/client.go:827: waiting for RPC address: plugin=/root/.tflint.d/plugins/github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-azurerm/0.26.0/tflint-ruleset-azurerm
04:41:56 [DEBUG] go-plugin@v1.6.1/client.go:1216: tflint-ruleset-azurerm: 04:41:56 [DEBUG] go-plugin@v1.6.0/server.go:419: plugin address: network=unix address=/tmp/plugin2134691030
04:41:56 [DEBUG] go-plugin@v1.6.1/client.go:880: using plugin: version=11
04:41:56 discovery.go:33: [INFO] Plugin "terraform" is not installed, but the bundled plugin is available.
04:41:56 discovery.go:54: [INFO] Plugin "terraform" found
04:41:56 [DEBUG] cmdrunner/cmd_runner.go:73: starting plugin: path=/usr/local/bin/tflint args=["/usr/local/bin/tflint", "--act-as-bundled-plugin"]
04:41:56 [DEBUG] cmdrunner/cmd_runner.go:80: plugin started: path=/usr/local/bin/tflint pid=1903
04:41:56 [DEBUG] go-plugin@v1.6.1/client.go:827: waiting for RPC address: plugin=/usr/local/bin/tflint
04:41:56 [DEBUG] go-plugin@v1.6.1/client.go:880: using plugin: version=11
04:41:56 [DEBUG] go-plugin@v1.6.1/client.go:1216: tflint: 04:41:56 [DEBUG] go-plugin@v1.6.1/server.go:419: plugin address: network=unix address=/tmp/plugin3885687210
04:41:56 [DEBUG] go-plugin@v1.6.1/grpc_stdio.go:142: stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error reading from server: read unix @->/tmp/plugin3885687210: read: connection reset by peer"
04:41:56 [INFO]  go-plugin@v1.6.1/client.go:780: plugin process exited: plugin=/usr/local/bin/tflint id=1903
04:41:56 [DEBUG] go-plugin@v1.6.1/client.go:558: plugin exited
04:41:56 [DEBUG] go-plugin@v1.6.1/grpc_stdio.go:142: stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error reading from server: EOF"
04:41:56 [INFO]  go-plugin@v1.6.1/client.go:780: plugin process exited: plugin=/root/.tflint.d/plugins/github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-azurerm/0.26.0/tflint-ruleset-azurerm id=1896
04:41:56 [DEBUG] go-plugin@v1.6.1/client.go:558: plugin exited
+ ruleset.terraform (0.9.1-bundled)
+ ruleset.azurerm (0.26.0)

Ive tried reinstalling the binaries, testing this locally, Ive tried removing both of the configs to no avail, I would like to get just a basic tflint running against this code and then move forward to rules

There isn't a useful error here for us to see. Best guess the tflint process spawned a dozen lines from the bottom of the log is erroring or crashing. Can you get any more information from that, e.g. try running it separately, look for any logs it might make, etc. ? Apologies I don't know tflint specifically.

Alternatively you might do better asking the tflint people directly for help, or suggestions how to get more info on the crash.
